# Deleting a node in the linklist

Tags: c++, data-structures

Here is my code to delete all the nodes having the value passed in the argument.

```
typedef struct nodetype
{
    int data;
    struct nodetype * next;
} node;

typedef node * list;


void Linklist::deleteNode(list * head, int value)
{

    list current = *head;
    list previous = *head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->data != value)
        {
              previous = current;
              current = current->next;
        }

        else if (current->data == value)
        {
            previous->next = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = previous->next;

        }
    }
}
```

But here if all the elements in the linklist is say 2, then it should delete all the elements in the linklist and finally head should also become NULL so that if I pass this head to count the number of nodes in the list it should say that the list is empty and other similar operations.

According to my current implementation the head is not becoming NULL for the above mentioned case.

Please suggest the modification so that head should become NULL if the linklist has all the nodes with the same value passed in the function argument.

Comment: If this isn't homework, try using the `std::list` container class. If this is homework, please add the `homework` tag to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified my code as follows and its working file now

```
void Linklist::deleteNode(list *head, int value)
{

    list * current = head;
    list * previous = head;
    bool flag = false;
    while(*current != NULL)
    {
        if((*current)->data != value)
        {
            *previous = *current;
            *current = (*current)->next;
        }

        else if ((*current)->data == value)
        {
            flag = true;
            (*previous)->next = (*current)->next;
            delete *current;
            *current = (*previous)->next;

        }
    }
    if(!flag)
        cout<<"Element not found in the linklist\n";
    cout<<"Count is "<<Linklist::count(*head)<<endl;
}
```